# How to compare 2 jsons and if one is bigger than other, add the missing ones to the json with less elements?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

I have an error in the data entry in one of my tables, so data I use is sometimes incomplete, as you can see in the example below, where some users have more questions answered then the others.

```
| user_id| user_name       | client_preferences                           
+--------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1020   | John Greene     | [{"fav_book": "1984", "fav_food": "Pizza"}]                     
+--------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3002   | Albert Onestone | [{"fav_food": "Fried Chicken"}]                                               
+--------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2334   | Luis Ville      | [{"fav_book": "Harry Potter", "fav_food": "Tacos", "fav_holiday":"christmas"}]
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------- --------------------+
```

As you can see some users have more preferences than the others. And this is a problem, because even if the client didn't have answered this question, we need them as null. Now we have a perfect example of user with all possible preferences in her profile:

```
| user_id| user_name       | client_preferences                           
+--------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0001   | Emma Write      | [{"fav_book": "Alice In the wonderland", "fav_food": "Hamburger", "fav_holiday":"christmas","fav_desert":"ice cream", "fav_pet":"dog", "fav_season":"fall"}]
+--------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

how can I check if all the users have these questions the user above has?  And, if they don't have some of the questions, how can I insert them as null in their profiles?

thanks!

Comment: Could you provide your dataframes as something someone can copy/paste into their interpreter? Is client_preferences actually a one element list of a dictionary?

Comment: *"check if all the users have these questions"* - do you have a predefined list of preferences?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest "Now we have a perfect example of user with all possible preferences in her profile..."

Comment: Is this json at some point or are you looking for an answer in pandas or one of the other frameworks you tagged?

Comment: Something like: `df.join(df['client_preferences'].str[0].apply(pd.Series))` might work... but optionally reindex the columns for a full know list before the join... but @JonSG question makes sense

Comment: I can share some of them in csv if you want! No, it's not a json, it's only a dictionary inside of a list. It WAS a json in another table but now it isn't. Sorry i used the wrong name

Comment: yes @JonSG i need and answer in pandas or pyspark, whatever you provide would be great, thanks

Comment: @MarcosDias My answer would be dictionary/json based so I'll let an expert in one of the those frameworks weigh in.

Comment: @MarcosDias what do you get if you run the code I posted above ?

Comment: @JonSG but what exactly do you have in mind? Because I don't even have a grasp of what to do here. Even a single idea could help

Comment: @MarcosDias If that answer does not help, just let me know and I will delete it.